# Cache MongoCollection's to improve MongoDB database query performance

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Is it a bad idea to store a cache of [MongoCollection](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1.htm)'s in the internal memory of the process to avoid the extra time waiting from calling [MongoDatabase::GetCollection()](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_CreateCollection.htm) queries multiple times and thus improving performance due to fewer roundtrips to the MongoDB database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) for the C# driver, `GetCollection()` and `CreateCollection` are framework methods only and do not read from the database. MongoDB creates a collection automatically when it is first used and therefore there is no need for these methods to connect and read from the database. Other methods, like `ListCollections`, do read from the database and it may be worth caching them to improve performance.

Comment: True, but only if you don't care about allocations